# "Continuity" of minimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

The following is a question I encountered while reading a topic on 'large deviations'. I abstract the problem here. I don't know whether the title is apt!

Let $\mathbb{A}=\{a_1,\dots,a_d\}$ be a finite set. The **Type** of a sequence $x_1^n:=x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{A}^n$ is defined to be the empirical probability distribution of $x_1^n$. That is, if $P$ is the type of $x_1^n$, then $$P(a_i)=\frac{\text{# of times } a_i \text{ appears in } x_1^n}{n}.$$ Think of $P$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ be the set of all types of sequences of length $n$. Then $\mathcal{P}_n\subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous, convex function. Let $\mathbb{\Pi}$ be an arbitrary set of probability distributions on $\mathbb{A}$, i.e., $\Pi\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, such that closure of $\Pi$ is equal to the closure of the interior of $\Pi$.

Let $\Pi_n:=\Pi\cap \mathcal{P}_n$, $D:=\inf_{P\in \Pi}f(P)$, and $D_n:=\inf_{P\in \Pi_n}f(P)$.

The problem is to show that $D_n\to D$ as $n\to \infty$. It looks intuitively clear. However, I couldn't get a rigorous argument to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you by chance have a reference to a freely available article/book that contains this? It would help me to understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's here http://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/CIT-004. This question arises in Theorem 2.1. The function $f$ I am talking about is called Kullback-Leibler divergence or the relative entropy.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  For a free version (for future viewers), this section is visible on google books (link is too long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll restate the problem as I understand it, please correct me if I am wrong.

Let $\Pi$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that for $\pi \in \Pi$, $\sum_i \pi_i = 1, \pi \geq 0$.  Furthermore, suppose that the closure of $\Pi$ is equal to the closure of the interior of $\Pi$.  Let $\Pi_n$ be those elements of $\Pi$ whose components are rational with a denominator that can be set to $n$.  Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0, \infty)$ be a continuous convex function.  Show
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{\pi_n \in \Pi_n} f(\pi_n) = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi} f(\pi)$$

Let $L = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi} f(\pi)$ and choose a sequence $p_m \in \Pi$ such that $$\lim_{m\to\infty} f(p_m) = L$$  Since $\Pi$ has the property that its closure equals the closure of its interior, we know that we can instead choose another sequence $\pi_m$ such that $\pi_m$ is the center of a ball contained in $\Pi$ for all $m$ and $f(\pi_m)$ also converges to $L$:
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} f(\pi_m) = L$$

Let $Q_n$ denote the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $\sum_i \pi_i = 1, \pi \geq 0$, and whose components are rational with a denominator that can be set to $n$. Now for each $m$, let $B_m$ denote the ball with $\pi_m$ at it's center.  Since the interior of $\Pi \subset \Pi$ that for some $n$ the set $Q_n \cap B_m \subset \Pi_n$.  So for each $m$ choose an $n \geq m$ and element $\pi'_n$ of $\Pi_n$ that lies within a distance of $2/n$ of $\pi_m$.  Denote this mapping from $m$ to $n$ by $n = g(m)$.  Now this sequence $\pi'_{g(m)}$ is cauchy with respect to $\pi_m$.  Therefore by the continuity of $f$:
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} f(\pi_{g(m)}') = \lim_{m \to \infty} f(\pi_m) = L$$

Comment: Your "pathological" $\Pi$ doesn't have the property of its closure being equal to the closure of its interior. Indeed your $\Pi$ has empty interior. Nonetheless, I think that you can let $Q$ be the set of all probability distributions on $\mathbb{A}$, and then consider $\Pi=Q \setminus \mathcal{P}_n$. Since $\mathcal{P}_n$ is finite, it is closed, so my example $\Pi$ is open. The closure of an open set is certainly equal to the closure of its interior, and my $\Pi$ is disjoint from $\mathcal{P}_n$.

Comment: @Ian - Great point.  It actually wouldn't be an issue for the theorem that just one (or finitely many) $\mathcal{P}_n$ have disjoint intersection with $\Pi$ since the limit could still exist.  I'll need to think more on the nature of this "closure being equal to the closure of its interior property".

Comment: You're right, if the closure is equal to the closure of the interior, then *eventually* some $\mathcal{P}_n$ will have to have nonempty intersection. Some of the infima for "small" $n$ might be infinity, but the later ones will have to be finite.

Comment: I have some questions. "Since $\Pi$ has the property that its closure equals the closure of its interior, we know that we can instead choose another sequence $\pi_m$ such that $\pi_m$ is the center of a ball contained in $\Pi$ for all $m$ and $f(\pi_m)$ also converges to $L$". Why? Do you mean every point of $\Pi$ is an interior point of $\Pi$?

Comment: "Since the interior of $\Pi\subset\Pi$ that for some $n$ the set $Q_n \cap \Pi \subset \Pi_n$". What do you mean here? Isn't $Q_n \cap \Pi = \Pi_n$?

Comment: @Ashok   I wouldn't go that far.  Instead, since the "closure equals the closure of its interior" then any point that is a limit of points in the set is also a limit point of points in the interior of the set.  So I first choose a limit point of the larger set $\Pi$.  Then I choose a sequence that converges to it from the interior of the set (i.e. the sequence $\pi$).

Comment: @Ashok - Regarding: "Since the interior of Π⊂Π that for some n the set Qn∩Π⊂Πn". What do you mean here? Isn't Qn∩Π=Πn?  Yes, that was a type, I updated the above.  There I am saying that for large enough $n$ the $Q_n$ that are within the radius of the ball are actually part of $\Pi_n$.

Comment: @muaddib: I'll take some time to fully understand this.